# jetty AsyncProxyServlet/AsyncMiddleManServlet

Tags: java, servlets, jetty-9

I am planning to use one of the above servlets. My use case is, client hits one of the server [This is where I would be using Proxy or MiddleMan servlet]. From here I would like to talk to other services based on the request URL. Can I use these servlets for this use case

example:

```
client -->http://<headend>/service1/x/y ---In MiddleManServlet -- http://server1/service1/x/y

client -->http://<headend>/service2/x/y ---In MiddleManServlet -- http://server2/service2/x/y
```

Can this be accomplished using this servlets?. I know I have to override rewriteTarget method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be accomplished using something like Jetty's AsyncProxyServlet.  You would basically need to set up your app container to pass requests with a certain path to your servlet ("service1" for example) and then in your servlet you would validate if the path the user was trying to hit was valid or whether it is an error (i.e. you probably don't want people proxying through your app to random services).

http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.11.v20160721/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/proxy/ProxyServlet.Transparent.html